# Vaadin 23.2.8 Trouble opening multiple Dialogs?

Tags: dialog, vaadin

if test:

```
ConfirmDialog dialog = new ConfirmDialog();
        dialog.setCloseOnEsc(false);
        dialog.setHeader("ok");
        dialog.setConfirmText("ok");
        dialog.setText(("ok"));
        dialog.open();

ConfirmDialog dialog1 = new ConfirmDialog();
        dialog1.setCloseOnEsc(false);
        dialog1.setHeader("ok1");
        dialog1.setConfirmText("ok1");
        dialog1.setText(("ok1"));
        dialog1.open();
```

No open 2 dialogs, but freeze application:

[image]

It should open two dialogs, in a hierarchical way.